# Constraint Layout not matching parent in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to get a Constraint Layout to match the parent (Navigation Drawer) because i don't need the Navigation Drawer menu list. I thought that the Navigation Drawer header could expand to take all the space but it seems it doesn't work. How can I get the header to match the size of the Navigation Drawer?

This is my Navigation View with the menu list removed:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"/>
<!--    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"-->

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the header Constraint Layout that should match the parent, the ImageView is constrained to the bottom.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E38080">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The header is in red, not matching the Navigation View height.

[image]

Comment: You men android icon should touch the top of the red?

Comment: No, the red should cover the entire Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the Navigation Header Layout (R.layout.design_navigation_item_header):

(This is the layout under which the layout specified in `app:headerLayout` will reside)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/design_navigation_separator_vertical_padding"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

**Since the height of this layout is `wrap_content`**, all children in it will be *wrapped to their normal size*, irrespective of setting their height to `match_parent`.

Well, then why my `headerLayout` occupies entire parent's width?

Because the width of its parent container is `match_parent`, the child views in it can freely expand to its parent's width (and that's why you see the red background across the entire width)

Comment: This answer does explain why your header is not expanding to the drawer layout but you can employ a hack utilizing this knowledge. If you can please try by setting `android:layout_height=0dp` and `android:layout_weight=1`  on your `ConstaintLayout`, it will expand to the height of the drawer layout. But you should rely on that as the underlying implementation can be changed in the future versions.